# I need to search text as a user types, but it can potentially be hundreds or thousands of pages, how can I do this efficiently

Tags: javascript, html, regex, search

I'm building a text entry field in javascript. But it's more like a text editor and will potentially contain huge documents, hundreds of pages in length. I need the user to be able to go anywhere in this text and make changes and highlight terms that match a certain set of regex. At the moment here's what I have:

```
var regexes = {
    thing_A: /\>(.*?)(?:(?!(\s|$)).)*/,
    thing_B: /\#(.*?)(?:(?!(\s|$)).)*/,
    thing_C: /@(.*?)(?:(?!(\s|$)).)*/,
    whitespace: /\s+/,
    other: /\S+/,
};
```

And I have code that runs on keypress. It checks for key "32" which is the spacebar. When spacebar is hit it joins the regexes and searches the document. This works fine for a small amount of text but will be quite taxing for large amounts. I potentially could just check for the last paragraph, but if someone goes back to the middle of the text and changes something I need to also track that.

**Is there a better way?**

Comment: "".indexOf() can be used a gate for RegExp since it's at  least 50X faster, sometimes 500X faster than complex regexps with nested clauses like you have. Eliminate as many RXs as possible with indexOf first, then get specific with the power of RXs.

Comment: Let's say there's 50 paragraphs, I just edited paragraph 34, once I know I'm in paragraph 34 I could split the entire text by \/n/n\ and regex array[33] but how do I find out which paragraph I just edited? Also, would splitting the text in this way be efficient? indexOf will give me the postition of the first occurence of a word, but there may be many occurences, lastIndexOf might be better, but if the word I added in paragraph 34 is also in paragraph 40 it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: if it's a textarea, you can use selectionStart to determin which paragraph was just edited. but you talk about highlighting, which would indicate a div. in that case, document.activeElement should reflect your paragraph. yes, splitting by"\n" will be MUCH faster than the regexp's posted, even on the whole text. using all the posted RXs on one paragraph will be about as fast as using indexOf on the whole, roughly and hypothetically speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
var regexes = {
    thing_X: /[>#@](.*?)(?:(?!(\s|$)).)*/,
    whitespace: /\s+/,
    other: /\S+/,
};
```